# стек на основе односвязного списка C++

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Не могу сообразить, как проверить на пустоту стек: 
...

```
struct List
{
    int x; //информационный элемент
    List *Next;
};
    bool Empty(List *&p)
    {
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

...

Comment: В данном случае никак, не факт, что там будет null, нужен счетчик глубины стэка, который при добавлении элемента инкрементировался, а при удалении декрементировался, правда если у вас будет много поточная версия, нужно эти операции выполнять атомарно

Comment: Через равенство нулевому указателю и проверяйте.